# Paste code into Word from VS without line numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-word

When I cut and paste code from Visual Studio 2008 into Word 2007, it includes line numbers at the start of every line. I am sure this didn't happen on my old PC, but I can't seem to find the option that would control this.

I don't want to paste as unformatted text, because I want the syntax colouring.

**UPDATE:** This was me being really stupid. I was pasting the code in just below a numbered list and Word decided that each line of code was a new entry in the numbered list. The numbers were in Courier so it looked like code line numbers as opposed to new entries in the list. Sorry. I guess this question should be closed.

Comment: What language is it? I've just tried it with C# with line numbers on and off and don't get them.

Comment: Didn't get line numbers with Visual C++ 2008 as well. The default settings don't seem to copy line numbers, though I'd find it interesting.

Comment: I can see some cases where you might want the line number - hmm

Comment: Extremely obvious but I managed to do the same. Very helpful question

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Wrote a document in *VS Code* and copied it over to *Confluence*, and I was able to see my text as a code snippet along with line numbers. (which I could not undo)

**Solution**:
I first had to copy the text from VS Code to Google Docs. Here I could again see the text as a code snippet (with black background and highlights for keywords).
The solution was to select the text in Google Docs, then go to the dropdown in tools and select `Normal Text`.
This converted the text to normal text (instead of code snippet).

I then copied the normal text to *Confluence* and the world looked beautiful again.